# 'pip install regressors' - error is : " python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully. "

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, setuptools

I can't install the **`regressors`** package with `pip install regressors` command in Windows 11.

The returned error is:

```
 python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [32 lines of output]
```

I have upgraded below libraries/dependencies.

```bash
pip install --upgrade pip
pip install --upgrade setuptools
pip install ez_setup
```

Tried many suggestions from Web, none of them worked  Any help would be
appreciated,

Answer (score 1):

I fixed a similar error when installing a different package by downgrading my version of setup tools:

```
pip install --upgrade pip setuptools==57.5.0
pip install {package}
```

I got to this solution from this: https://github.com/Thibauth/python-pushover/issues/42

Answer (score 0):

Clone this library into your project, remove `use_2to3` argument from ***setup.py*** in `regressors` package you cloned then install it with pip using below command and after that you can use this package in your project:

```bash
pip install -e ./name_of_your_clone_instance
```

Comment: Clone from which location ?
I downloaded  "regressors-0.0.3.tar.gz" file ,it has only one file

Comment: clone this git repository: https://github.com/nsh87/regressors.git

Comment: clone it using git, don't download it as .tar.gz package.